# How do you login to a webpage and retrieve its content in C#?

Tags: c#, http, authentication, screen-scraping

How do you login to a webpage and retrieve its content in C#?

Comment: I didn't downmod you, but you should rephrase your question. Are you trying to build an ASP.NET webpage with login capabilities? Or are you just trying to log into a webpage?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.

Comment: I was confused at first, too, but after reading it a couple times I'm pretty sure he means screen scraping.

Comment: I think he's trying to write a bot to go in and screen-scrape a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string postData = "userid=ducon";
            postData += "&username=camarche" ;
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(
                URL);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = data.Length;
            Stream newStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            newStream.Close();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
            string coco = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 5):

That depends on what's required to log in. You could use a webclient to send the login credentials to the server's login page (via whatever method is required, GET or POST), but that wouldn't persist a cookie. There is a [way](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html) to get a webclient to handle cookies, so you could just POST the login info to the server, then request the page you want with the same webclient, then do whatever you want with the page.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `System.Net.WebClient`, or for more advanced requirements `System.Net.HttpWebRequest/System.Net.HttpWebResponse`.

As for actually applying these:  you'll have to study the html source of each page you want to scrape in order to learn exactly what Http requests it's expecting.

Answer (score 2):

How do you mean "login"?

If the subfolder is protected on the OS level, and the browser pops of a login dialog when you go there, you will need to set the Credentials property on the HttpWebRequest.

If the website has it's own cookie-based membership/login system, you will have to use HttpWebRequest to first response to the login form.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) class.

```
Dim Html As String

Using Client As New System.Net.WebClient()
    Html = Client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com")
End Using
```

Comment: He asked for C# code, probably (it wasn't me that downvoted it)

Comment: The C# is almost identical- just a parenthese, braces, a semi-colon, and change the case of a few keywords.

Comment: Come on, people.  If you can read/write C#, you can read/write VB.  Open your mind!

Comment: I downvoted because he mentioned that he needs to login before he downloads the page. The stock webclient wouldn't support cookies for a login session, so the solution didn't exactly fit the problem.

Comment: The C# answer (mine) got downvoted too. I suppose it was the authentication thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build in WebClient Object instead of crating the request yourself.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
string url = "http://foo.com";          
try
{
    using (Stream stream = wc.OpenRead(new Uri(url)))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
             }
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    //Error handeling
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
public string GetContent(string url)  
{ 
  using (System.Net.WebClient client =new System.Net.WebClient()) 
  { 
  return client.DownloadString(url); 
  } 
}
```